# Is there an intuitive interpretation of precision always higher than recall?

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, interpretation

I have a multiclass-classifier whose **macro-precision** is always greater than **macro-recall**. I suppose it means false negatives outnumber false positives in general. Is there an intuitive interpretation about this?

[image: score]

Answer (score 3):

Generally lower recall means that the system is too strict, i.e. it predicts an instance as positive only when it has clear indications in the features that it's indeed a positive. As a consequence, it misses the true positive instances for which the indications are not so clear.

But when looking at macro-recall it's more complex: it depends primarily on how many classes there are and their distribution. In case of imbalance a very common problem is that the system predicts the majority class too often, causing a low recall for the minority class(es) and therefore a lower macro-recall. The only way to check for this is to look at the performance of individual classes.

Comment: oh this is very intuitive. Thank you!